# Dynamically allocating 1D array of structs : Two Methods

Tags: c++

I have allocated a 1D array of structs by 2 methods, which I believe to give me contiguous memory allocation. But when I output the memory locations I see Type 1 allocates with a difference of 4bytes but Type 2 takes 32bytes. Could you please explain why this happens.

Thanks!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
}str;


int main(){
    int i;
    str **str_ptr;
    str *str_ptr1;
    str_ptr = (str **)malloc(5*sizeof(str *));
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){str_ptr[i]=malloc(sizeof(str));}
    str_ptr1 = (str *)malloc(5*sizeof(str));
    printf("Type 1 : %p and %p \n",str_ptr1,str_ptr1+1);
    printf("Type 2 : %p and %p \n",str_ptr[0],str_ptr[1]);
}
```

Type 1 : 0xb830e0 and 0xb830e4

Type 2 : 0xb83040 and 0xb83060

Comment: One is an array of pointers to structs, the other an actual array of structs.

Comment: Just curious about why you are using C-style malloc in this manner for a C++ program, if you know the size beforehand (5 above), use `std::array`, if you need to allocate on the heap, I'd recommend one of the standard containers.

Comment: @JakeHeidt I was just trying to clear up my concepts..  So.. anyways thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Some_guy just by the way, the difference in type2 isn't 20 Bytes, it's 32 bytes (0x20 = 32)

Comment: Ah!! right.. Missed that.. Corrected!!

Comment: Please note that the last allocation should be `str_ptr1 = (str *)malloc(5*sizeof(str));` or `str_ptr1 = (str *)malloc(5 * sizeof *str_ptr1);`. Also, you are leaking memory.

Comment: The best way to do this is `std::vector<str> my_strs(5);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two very different things. The first, `str_ptr`, is more like an array of *pointers* to the structure. The second, `str_ptr1`, is an array of structure *objects*.

The variables `str_ptr` and `str_ptr1` are roughly equivalent to

```
str *str_ptr[5];
str str_ptr1[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Type 1: - Here you are printing the address of 2 integers allocated from a single call to malloc.

Type 2: - Here you are printing the addresses returned from 2 DIFFERENT calls to malloc.

Comment: The important point being that in type 2, there's no guarantee that the two pointers are even remotely near each other in memory. In this case they are 20-bytes apart, but with a different compiler or a slight change to the code this could change unpredictably, as the separate calls to malloc can return pointers to any memory location they see fit.